# Unable to load "foreach" library in RStudio

Tags: r, foreach, package, doparallel

I'm going to work with 'doParallel' package, that requires 'foreach' package to be loaded. However, some strange error occurs with the error message copied below.

Yesterday I've updated R to 3.6.0 version. Could it be causing the problem?

```
install.packages("foreach")
library(foreach)
```

> library(foreach)
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘foreach’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
> number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)